# windows 7 sftp doesn't connect, ssh works

Tags: windows-7, ssh, sftp

I use BitKinex on Windows 7 as SFTP client and PuTTY for ssh remote shell.

Out of the blue, sftp stopped working, but putty still connects normaly.

Tried disableing firewall (Avast Internet Security), no changes.

I was under the impression that sftp works "over" ssh, so I am confused right now...

Where should I look for the problem?

ps. using private-public key auth for ssh and sftp.

edit:
BitKinex log:

```
Resolving host name "example.com" ...
Connecting ( example.com => ip: 178.218.166.77, port: 22 )
Connected (178.218.166.77:22)
Initializing the SSH session ...
The server is running SSH2
Key (re)exchange started
New keys in use
Authentication service requested
User authentication started (type: publickey)
Opening channel
Opening sftp subsystem
<<< INIT (version: 3)
```

Comment: You're right about SFTP being an SSH protocol.  Did you recently install updates? I know SP1 recently came out... maybe it has something to do with that...

Comment: Does BitKinex have any sort of debug output? Does it give any messages as an error? "stopped working" is a pretty all-catching problem and it would be really useful to get more information how its breaking. I've been trying to find out where to get this information from their website but I can't see anything obvious. Personally I use winscp.

Comment: Have you tried WinSCP, or the `psftp` client that comes with PuTTY? Do they work?

Comment: @PriceChild edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question...

There was an `read` command in my `.bashrc` file, so user needs to press any key to get bash prompt.

Commenting out the `read` solved the problem.